# The reason of ImportError: No module named requests

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I installed requests to use 'pip3 install requests, but always ImportError: No module named requests.

```
import requests
res=requests.get("http://naver.com")
print("response :", res.status_code)
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably because your `pip3` is not for your `python`.

```
which pip
which python
```

may show different paths.

Correct the path or try:

```
python -m pip install requests
```